# Can I use html files like classes to build a page?

Tags: css, html

I'm new to HTML5 (and don't know much about programing languages as .net or C#). But I'm learning and have a doubt. Hope you can help me.

Can I, for exemple, create separeted files for the navigation bar code, a grid of posts, etc, and then create a page calling them, like classes in .net?

I don't know if I'm being clear, but the reason is: I want to be able to edit a file with the navbar alone, then another file with the footer, an update all pages. Without using iFrame.

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a principle of modularization. Natively it is not possible with HTML. Though you can achieve it with some scripting (Javascript / JQuery). Though, frameworks like Angular and React are build around this idea. It create modules for the rendering (HTML) and the logic behind it (Javascript).

Comment: HTML has nothing like classes in the Object Oriented programming sense. OTOH, what you seem to be asking is completely different, namely dividing a page into separate files. That’s not possible in HTML either, except in the old dull sense of using frames. What you probably really need is good authoring tools, but that’s off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You really should look into php for that kind of functionality. Then you can use:

```
 <?php include ("shared_assets/this_file.php")?>
```

for example...but you have a lot to learn, so why not start out with a basic php course :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I'm learning HTML5 and CSS, now. I'm looking for a way to create reusable elements and make my work to create Landing Pages faster.

Would like to use something without a server like Apache or NGinx. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can if you use Polymer (https://www.polymer-project.org/).  But as @mayersdesign said, you should look into PHP for this kind of thing.

Comment: Interesting link!

Comment: Thanks for the link. =)

Answer (score 0):

Like the answers above mentioned, you can't do this with just simple html and css. Php is great for this. Below are some examples from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

Learning php will be a great benefit for you.